# jquery adding decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add together decimal numbers but when i alert the variable `finalnumber` i get zero. The variable `number` is a decimal number.  How do i solve this so that variable `finalnumber` is the sum of all `number`?

```
var finalnumber = 0;

$('#chosen-keyword-container').find('.keyword-row').each(function() {
    var number = $(this).find('td:last').find('input[name=bid-price[]]').val();

    var finalnumber = parseInt(number) + parseInt(finalnumber);

});​
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your issue, but you may want parseFloat if you are looking at decimal numbers.

Comment: What is exactly in the input fields? Did you try '.' and ',' as well as the decimal separator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
var finalnumber = parseInt(number)+parseInt(finalnumber);
```

To this:

```
finalnumber = finalnumber + parseFloat(number);
```

Or:

```
finalnumber += parseFloat(number);
```

- `parseInt` **can't hold decimal values**. use `parseFloat` instead.
- Don't declare `finalnumber` with `var`, becuase it hides the `finalnumber` in the outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the `var` keyword inside your function in front of `finalnumber`. With that `var` you define a new variable under that name and scope. So basically you have two versions of `finalnumber` and just add to the local one (the one inside the function and not the global one).

On the other hand you should change `parseInt` to `parseFloat` as you are working with decimal numbers (See answer of @gdoron).

```
$('#chosen-keyword-container').find('.keyword-row').each(function() {
  var number = $(this).find('td:last').find('input[name=bid-price[]]').val();

  finalnumber = parseFloat(number) + finalnumber;  
});
```

On a sidenote: You can drop the `parseInt()` inside the function for `finalnumber`. This variable is always a number value and so there is no need to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

change the addition line as follows

```
finalnumber = finalnumber + parseFloat(number);
```